# Linear Programming $\boldsymbol{c}^T \boldsymbol{x}$ s.t. $\boldsymbol{Ax} = \boldsymbol{b}$

Tags: linear-programming

Prove for the linear programming 
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
 min & \boldsymbol{c}^T \boldsymbol{x} \\
 s.t.  & \boldsymbol{Ax} = \boldsymbol{b} \end{array} \right.  
\end{equation}
has only two results:

1. the objective function dose not have lower bound.
2. all the feasible solutions are optimal.

if the feasible domain is not empty.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. All feasible solutions will be optimal if the objective function is just a constant right?

Comment: @Jack Yes, the objective function is constant in result 2.